# What is the method to get a REAL from SUM using ORMLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite, object-relational-model

I have various `double` values in my database. To get the sum of them all I am using

`relvantDao.queryRawValue("SELECT SUM(productPrice * productQuantity) FROM cart");`

Problem is that this only returns a `long` value, hence the decimal points are lost. How can I get the `REAL` sum of these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is that this only returns a long value, hence the decimal points are lost. How can I get the REAL sum of these values?

If you look at the [ORMLite docs on raw queries](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries), you can see that there is a number of ways to use the raw queries with different field types.  To quote:

> You can also map the results into your own object by passing in a RawRowMapper object. This will call the mapping object with an array of strings and allow it to convert the strings into an object...
>
> You can also define your own custom mapper if the results are more complex.

This would look something like:

```
GenericRawResults<Double> rawResults =
   orderDao.queryRaw(
      "SELECT SUM(productPrice * productQuantity) FROM cart",
      new RawRowMapper<Double>() {
         public Double mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] resultColumns){
            return Double.parseDouble(resultColumns[0]);
         }
    });
```

There are other examples in the ORMLite docs.  For example, you can specify a `DataType[]` argument and have ORMLite do the extraction from the database natively to a `Double` as well.